# ERRO no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Apareceu esse erro do nada e agora eu não consigo emular o app no celular quanto no simulador segue o erro.

> Error:C:\Users\Rodolfo.gradle\caches\2.8\scripts\asLocalRepo19_3gzxk3w9gvngw8gydvjit5r7x\cp_init\cache.properties
>   (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma vez tive esse problema e resolvi com esse link do Stackoverflow em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024954/cache-properties-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

1. Acesse o diretório C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.8\
2. Copie a pasta scripts e cole em outro lugar para recolocar no lugar em caso não funcione.
3. Delete a pasta scripts do diretório C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.8\
4. Sincronize o projeto;

Depois disso o Android Studio irá gerar novos arquivos de cache, pra mim funcionou, espero ter ajudado.