# Cache.properties, arquivo não encontrado

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, instalei o Android Studio no meu notebook (SO: Windows 10) e quando gerei minha aplicação básica "Hello World" tentei executar no meu celular e apareceu o seguinte erro:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Didi&Lulu\.gradle\caches\2.10\classAnalysis\cache.properties (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
```

Encontrei uma pergunta fechada [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109217/erro-no-android-studio), porém, não resolveu o que ele sugeriu.

Comment: Tente criar o arquivo `cache.properties` nesse diretório,sem nenhum conteúdo, aqui no meu ele existe, junto com outros.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, siga esses passos para resolver seu problema:

1. Vá até o diretório C:\Users\Didi&Lulu\ .gradle\caches\2.10
2. Copie a pasta **scripts** e salve em algum lugar, caso precise
       dela de volta depois;
3. Delete a pasta **scripts** desse diretório, mantendo sua cópia
       salva em algum lugar como backup;
4. Depois sincronize seu projeto novamente, no botão Sync, que
       aparece na barra amarela no topo das classes ou na própria IDE no
       menu Build / Rebuild project;

Abraços.

Comment: Olá amigo, Já tentei essa alternativa. Porém, não solucionou o problema. Mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Me deparei com esse problema enquanto fazia meu TCC. Consegui resolver o problema assim: Copiei o arquivo 'cache.properties' de qualquer uma outra pasta, colei na pasta que indicava o erro, fiz o rebuild e pronto.
Consegui fazer a entrega do meu TCC sem erros

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema assim: Copiei o arquivo 'cache.properties' de qualquer uma outra pasta, colei na pasta que indicava o erro, fui em file, depois sync project with gradle files e depois rebuild e pronto.